# How is consciousness linked to the brain?

Tags: brain

Could the brain be working without consciousness? Does the brain interact with consciousness? Alternately, is it that consciousness can't really control the brain, and you only have the impression that you make the decisions, but your brain does.

If the answer to the last question is yes, it is impossible to know if someone else has a consciousness? Even if he doesn't, he'll say he does, because the brain thinks he does.

We can't be made only from matter. If we would, we'd be a mix of chemicals interacting with each other. What makes us be aware of our feelings, what we think, and our 5 senses?

When and how is consciousnesses created?

Comment: Unfortunately, although this is a very well researched area in neuroscience, I think we do not know the answer yet. Anyway good question! I would slightly edit it, however, to make it a bit more "biological" and a bit less phylosophical

Comment: Note that consciousness and mechanicism are not mutually exclusives. We, at the same time, can be both conscious and mere chemicals. Because this question lie at the limit between philosopy and biology I suggest you to search at [http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), for example [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/966/what-are-the-necessary-conditions-for-an-action-to-be-regarded-as-a-free-choice) and [here](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/what-makes-humans-different-from-a-chemical-computer). Good question, though.

Comment: "A mix of chemicals interacting with each other" is a great way to describe organisms.

Comment: @Someone Great question. One point I'd make though is that 'We can't be made only from matter' is a statement that makes assumptions about the nature of matter. Matter is not like Lego. From what I remember from my uni physics courses, matter is actually pretty weird... i.e. non-intuitive. At least on the smallest scales.

Comment: A non-subjective definition of consciousness is **needed first** . I would go with "a created system that decides pro-activity and is given freedom to think for **itself** "